Not able to detect nearby NFC tag
I want to transfer amount between two Android devices through NFC .
I tried to detect the NFC tag by using below code. But I got error:

TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object.

import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import NfcManager, {NfcTech} from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

// Pre-step, call this before any NFC operations
NfcManager.start();

const LoginScreen = () => {
  async function readNdef() {
    try {
      // register for the NFC tag with NDEF in it
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      // the resolved tag object will contain `ndefMessage` property
      const tag = await NfcManager.getTag();
      if (tag) {
        console.warn('Tag found', tag);
      } else {
        console.warn('No tag found');
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn('Oops!', ex);
    } finally {
      // stop the nfc scanning
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.wrapper}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={readNdef}>
        <Text>Scan a Tag</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {  
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;


Does this answer your question? Emulate NDEF Tag in ReactNative for Android

The problem is you have written only one side of the code, reading the Tag and being a Tag is two totally different bits of code. I don't think there is a React Native Module to be a Tag. Also this is very Advanced NFC and only possible on Android.

We are not trying to emulate, We want to send some text to the other device using NFC when two Android mobile phones are in close Proximity. Actually we want to try out payment from one digital wallet to another digital wallet using NFC between phones . We need source code for this.

That's the problem you cannot just send text between 2 NFC devices without one of them emulating a NFC Tag. NFC does not work how you are trying to use it.
